# Convert value number key to string php?

Tags: php

Here is my code :

```
 foreach($urlImages as $key => $u){

        $nameImg = $id_product.'_'.$key.'_'.md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).'.png';

    }
```

The key value is incremented, I want to change the key number to a string like:

```
if $key=1 i want $key=white
if $key=2 i want $key=black
```

Comment: if don't you use if else condition with loop  ?

Comment: and if `$key == 3` , what color?

Comment: and if $key == 4 ?

Comment: i have juste 1 2 & 3 , if key = 3 color grey

Comment: and if `$key == 5`?

Comment: @psppro26, you should post all possible colors and relations "key - color" into your question

Answer (score 0):

@psppro26 simple try the concept like below:

```
<?php
$color = array(1 => "white", 2 =>"black", 3 => "grey");
foreach($urlImages as $key => $u){

        $nameImg = $id_product.'_'.$color[$key].'_'.md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).'.png';

}
```

Comment: Try to make a function which get color depending on key.

Comment: and if the colors are fixed like they are only three then hard code can be used

Comment: we can also use switch case and if else condition

Comment: but for colors more than 10, needs to get it from database.

Comment: yeah but he want to perform on only 3 color that are fixed, so here the hard code can be worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139496/discussion-between-bunker-boy-and-prashant-g-patil).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be something like that

```
/* here you declare what should be swap to what, it can be in order, or you can index them manually */
$arrayToSwap = [
    1 => 'white',
    2 => 'black'
 ];
/* Here you change keys for future use */
$newArray = []
foreach ($urlImages as $key => $uu) {
    $newArray[$arrayToSwap[$key]] = $u;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) case:

```
 foreach($urlImages as $key => $u){
    $type = 'default';

    switch ($key) {
      case 1:
        $type = 'white';
        break;
      case 2:
        $type = 'black';
        break;
    }

    $nameImg = $id_product.'_'.$type.'_'.md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).'.png';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyNameMap = [
   1=>'white',
   2=>'black'
];

// some codes
foreach ($urlImages as $key => $name) {
    $nameImg = $id_product.'_'.$keyNameMap[$key].'_'.md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).'.png';
    // come codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$keys = ['white','black','blue','pink'];
$urlImages = ['photo1','photo2','photo3','photo4'];

print_r($urlImages);
$urlImages= array_combine($keys, array_values($urlImages));

print_r($urlImages);
```

first print_r Array ( [0] => photo1 [1] => photo2 [2] => photo3 [3] => photo4 )

second print_r will return Array ( [white] => photo1 [black] => photo2 [blue] => photo3 [pink] => photo4 )

Answer (score -1):

You can use  Comparison Operators if the choice is only a few

```
$result = ($value == $condition?)valTrue : valFalse;
```

this an example for your case 1 for white, 2 for black and 3 for grey.

```
 <?php
        $urlImages = array(  "1" => "test.png","2" => "test2.png", "3" => "test3.png");
        foreach($urlImages as $key => $u){
          $nameImg[] = $id_product.'_'.($key == 1?'white':($key == 2?'black':'grey')).'_'.md5(uniqid(rand(0,1000), true)).'.png';
        }
        print_r($nameImg);
        ?>
```

/*result*/

```
Array
(
    [0] => _white_6c4f456490be5893166478b2d35912ad.png
    [1] => _black_eb4c071837bf74ce6b9c1c445ff230f7.png
    [2] => _grey_80615be519a0d7db22a8241dc365acb9.png
)
```

Comment: Maybe? Why maybe?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.